# Why do I get '0' instead of values while comparing '' or blank cell in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data as in the first picture.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmnVq.png)
I have written code as:

```
test_data = pd.read_excel('all_test_doc.xlsx')
conditions = [ test_data['Area Code'] == 'A56',test_data['Area Code'] == 'A90',test_data['Area 
Code'] == 'A20',test_data['Area Code'] == '']
values = [ 'Mount Bundy', 'Downhill', "Paterson", 'No data']
test_data['Area Name'] = np.select(conditions, values)
test_data.to_excel("test_output.xlsx")
```

I want to obtain a result as:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMZlo.png)

But landed in the following result:
[Result with 0 in Blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9ize.png)

How do I get result as in pc 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can try change test empty values:

```
test_data['Area Code'] == ''
```

to test missing values:

```
test_data['Area Code'].isna()
```

Or to test mising values or empty values:

```
test_data['Area Code'].fillna('') == ''
```